# ReactJs - Justify Navbar items

Tags: css, reactjs

**Goal**
I am working with ReactJS and I am trying to dynamically justify all items within my Nav/Navbar as shown in the examples below.

**Ex:**
[image]

**Problem:**
I have looked into some options such as appending "justified" to the `Nav` tag, but this ended up squishing all of my NavItems/MenuItems together. I tried wrapping my `Nav` inside of a `div`, giving it a `className`, and then trying modify the alignment using: `text-align: center` in the .css file. Unfortantely, this did nothing to alter the alignment

**Navigation Compoonent**

```
/* Basic Functionality Imports */
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUserGroup } from './Auth.jsx';

/* All page imports */
import GenReports from '../pages/GenReports';
import IntlReports from '../pages/IntlReports';

var isDev = getUserGroup() === "dev" ? true : false;
var isAdmin = getUserGroup() === "admin" ? true : false;
var isDataAnalyst = getUserGroup() === "analyst" ? true : false;

/*
*  Below is an example of conditional rendering
*  Using the above variables as shorthand, each "render" performs a check against the user role
*  to determine if the navigation bar should render that piece of the navigation component.
*  The final navbar pushed to the component that utilizes the Navigation componenet will never
*  know the existance of the non-rendered pieces, helping to prevent potential security issues
*/
var renderUserVerify = !isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={1.1}><NavLink to="/UserVerfication">USER VERIFICATION</NavLink></MenuItem> : null;
var renderPkgLookup = !isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={1.2}><NavLink to="/PkgInqueryn">PACKAGE INQUERY</NavLink></MenuItem> : null;
var renderQuerySearch = !isDataAnalyst ? <NavDropdown eventKey={1} title="QUERY SEARCHES" id="query-nav-dropdown">
                                           {renderUserVerify}
                                           {renderPkgLookup}
                                         </NavDropdown> : null;

var renderUpdateUser = isDev || isAdmin ? <NavItem eventKey={2}><NavLink to="/UpdateUser">UPDATE USER</NavLink></NavItem> : null;

var renderGenReports = isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}><NavLink to="/reports/GenReports">GENERAL REPORTS</NavLink></MenuItem> : null;
var renderIntlReports = isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}><NavLink to="/reports/IntlReports">INTERNATIONAL REPORTS</NavLink></MenuItem> : null;
var renderReports = isDev || isAdmin || isDataAnalyst ? <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="REPORTS" id="reports-nav-dropdown">
                                                          {renderGenReports}
                                                          {renderIntlReports}
                                                        </NavDropdown> : null;
var renderUserPref = !isDataAnalyst ? <NavItem eventKey={4}><NavLink to"/UserPref">USER PREFERENCE</NavLink></NavItem> : null;

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar inverse fluid collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand>
                <><NavLink to="/"> HOME </NavLink>
              </Navbar.Brand>
              <Navbar.Toggle />
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
              <Nav justified>
                {renderQuerySearch}
                {renderUpdateUser
                {renderReports}
                {renderUserPref}
                <NavItem eventKey={5}><NavLink to="/Help">HELP</NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey={6}><NavLink to="/logout">LOGOUT</NavItem>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
          <Route path="/GenReports" component={GenReports} />
          <Route path="/IntlReports" component={IntlReports} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>I am your Overlord! Fear me!</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
      <NavLink to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</NavLink><br />
      <NavLink to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</NavLink><br />
      <NavLink to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</NavLink><br />

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.url}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
);
```

**Sample Reports Page**  (all currently look similar)

```
import React from 'react';

export default class IntlReports extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <h1>You have reached the International Reports Page</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**Output HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link type="text/css" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      .centerMe {
        margin: 0;
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
      .App {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .App-logo {
        -webkit-animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
                animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
        height: 80px;
      }

      .App-header {
        background-color: #222;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 20px;
        color: white;
      }

      .App-title {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }

      .App-intro {
        font-size: large;
      }

      @-webkit-keyframes App-logo-spin {
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }

      @keyframes App-logo-spin {
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"><div class="App">
      <header class="App-header">
        <img src="/static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg" class="App-logo" alt="logo">
        <h1 class="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-brand active" aria-current="true" href="/"> HOME </a>
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="centerMe nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a id="query-nav-dropdown" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">QUERY SEARCHES <span class="caret"></span></a>
                 <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="query-nav-dropdown">
                   <li role="presentation" class="">
                     <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"><a aria-current="false" href="/PkgLookup">PACKAGE LOOKUP</a></a>
                   </li></ul></li>
                <li role="presentation" class=""><a role="button" href="#"><a aria-current="false" href="/Help">HELP</a></a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class=""><a role="button" href="#"><a aria-current="false" href="/logout">LOGOUT</a></a></li>
           </ul></div></div></nav>
           <div><h2>I am your Overlord! Fear me!</h2></div></div></div></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script rel="stylesheet" type="javascript" href="../node_modules/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

**App.css**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 80px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

**Rendered/Output CSS**

```
element.style {
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html[Attributes Style] {
    -webkit-locale: "en";
}
user agent stylesheet
html {
    display: block;
}
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In duplicating, you may have to manually alter `isDev`, `isAdmin`, and/or `isAnalyst` to have one be `true` to help modify the rendering

**Question:**
Does anyone know the proper way to dynamically justify/center the Navbar items?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @brandon: Can you please share your code snippet so we can take a look at it ? :)

Comment: I just finished added it at the request of @Paulie_D

Comment: We'd need the output HTML & CSS at a mnimum but this has come up on SO *many* times before.

Comment: @Paulie_D i will add the css, but I do not know what you are  mean by the html. I mean, I can provide the index.html file, but that is practically the default... eh, I'll add it anyways

Comment: @Brandon , with "output HTML" he meant the one rendered by React, not the `index.html`. This is because your problem doesn't seem like a React problem, but just a CSS problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D I added the requested code. It took me a minute to get it all as it copied as a single line, so I had to fix it to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation there's a prop for Nav called justify, setting

`<Nav className="justify-content-end nav" justify="true">
    ...
</Nav>`

and setting the nav class to `flex: 1;` so that it takes all the space in Navbar should work.